# CI/CD for laravel project how to make it stable

Tags: php, laravel, docker, jenkins

I'd like to use jenkins for my laravel project.

I use pipeline for that. As you know, laravel doesn't need build step. I also don't use tests. I just want to have a `stage('deploy').` When making  push to repository, `jenkins` host gets notified, pulls the project and runs the jenkins pipeline resided in `laravel` project. As i have `jenkins host` and `laravel api` host different from each other, this is where I am facing issues.

As I said, I don't have `build` and `test` stages. so only `deploy` in `pipeline`. but to run `laravel` project, before using `jenkins`, i had `bash` script which had 10 lines of code in it. such as `(changing permissions, making current user as my user, running composer install, running docker-compose and so on)`.As I have another host for Laravel , I have 2 options:

1) in `stage('deploy')` I can transfer build.sh file from jenkins host to laravel api host. and then making ssh into that laravel api host and running that file there. The thing I don't like about this is that what if setting permissions or other stuff that I have in that build.sh file go wrong in halfway which will get my project in an undesired state and I won't even get notified and I will have the broken project in production.

2) I can do all the stuff in `stage('build')` running `'composer install and other stuff`, after that making `dockerfile` from it(including vendor folder) and then after getting the image (which contains vendor too), uploading this docker image into dockerhub, then in stage('deploy') i can notify remote host about that and pass the script file from jenkins to that laravel remote hosts which contains the code which pulls the latest image from dockerhub and run it. this way I won't have undesired state as that image already contains vendor folder, it already got permissions and all that stuff. The issue with this is that making image will take lots of hard-disk. and imagine creating images for every push on the repository.

What do you suggest I should do?

Answer (score 0):

Standard practice is your option 2, to make a new image for every build.  Generally in Docker you don’t independently copy source code around at all; you build images and deal only with those images.  (The “Docker for development” pattern of building and image and then replacing all of its contents with your local source tree is not at all how Docker is generally used in a production environment.)

You should make sure you give every image a unique identifier, like the timestamp of the build or some sort of source control commit ID.  This is all but required for some higher-level automation systems (Kubernetes, for example), and it makes it very easy to roll back a broken build.

In the workflow you’ve described, you can package up pretty much any sort of files into an image and send them off to be run.  There’s a great deal of value in having some sort of validation phase to make sure that an embarrassing typo doesn’t result in an image that never starts at all.  By which I mean...write tests :-)

Comment: Thanks for answering. but I don't understand what you mean by "Standard practice is your option 2, to make a new image for every build. Generally in Docker you don’t independently copy source code around at all; you build images and deal only with those images. (The “Docker for development” pattern of building and image and then replacing all of its contents with your local source tree is not at all how Docker is generally used in a production environment.)".  If I make build images for every push on repository, my jenkins host is gonna be super huge and for no reason-I don't run project here

Comment: Once you’ve `docker push`ed your images to a repository, you can safely `docker system prune` to reclaim space.

Comment: so you like my option 2. making image (which installs packages, runs composer install , then moving my source code with vendor folder into that image) and pushing that image to docker hub? and making system prune?  Do you like this way right? If the answer is yes, what about docker hub? if I make pushing to github repository 100th times a day, imagine in a month, i have 3000 images in docker hub. imagine that for a year.